# Implementing binary search in a sorted text file?

Tags: c++, file, search

Is there a way by which instead of copying the data of file directly implement search in it?

Comment: Short answer - yes

Comment: Not really - binary search requires random access, and you can't effectively perform random access on a text file (i.e. a file made up of variable length lines).

Comment: @NeilButterworth you can scan for the nearest carriage return, or file may contain fixed length records.

Comment: @NeilButterworth You *can* perform random access in a file's data. It's up to the file format if that random access is meaningful or not.

Comment: @Francois Which is why I said "effectively".

Comment: @NeilButterworth You could jump to a random place in file, search for a new linebreak and continuing from there. The algorithm would be still a little more complicated than standard binary search but it would be entirely possible. It makes sense only if files are large, though.

Comment: @Slava Which is why I qualified my comment with "variable length lines".

Comment: @NeilButterworth which is why I said it either fixed length or you can scan for next `\n`

Comment: @Slava Just that then it technically wouldn't be binary search (with respect to line records if they were variable-length).

Comment: @DanielLangr why not? You find position in file by binary search, you just adjust it by actual data. Still binary search.

Comment: @Slava That's why I wrote _"with respect to line records"_, since such algorithm might move over records in a different way than true binary search algorithm. Imagine a file where you have 100 single-character lines and one 1000000 character line. Just finding `\n` of the latter effectively makes searching linear.

Comment: @DanielLangr the fact that it will not work efficiently in such case does not mean it is not binary search anymore AFAIK

Comment: @Slava I am not sure whether _O(log n)_ complexity is guaranteed in this case. Just another example that came to my mind: Suppose `i`th line of the input file has `2<<i` characters.

Answer (score 0):

in theory: yes, but it will be quite inefficient.

i'd recommend to put the data in a sqlite database, that way you still have a single file, but can nicely query/search for entries.

Answer (score -1):

tl;dr: Yes, but it's often not worth it

You neglected to mention how the text file is sorted, exactly, and whether there are escaped characters, quotation marks, multi-octet characters etc. - these would all impact the answer.

But let's make the following assumptions:

- Plain printable ASCII text, with no newlines in each string.
- Newlines (i.e. 0xA characters) separate strings.

This is still not enough for a set of assumptions, because - maybe some of the strings are much longer than the others? In fact, what about the not-that-extreme case of n strings overall, but a few of them take up most of the characters? If you start sampling characters in the file, you'll need to go back and forth, linearly, at least to both edges of a single string (or forwarded until you hit a newline twice).

So let's add more assumptions, although frankly - they're quite invalid:

- You know the minimum Min and maximum Max string lengths.
- The ratio R of minimum to maximum length is not very high

This makes it at least theoretically reasonable to start reading from some arbitrary point in the file, and look for a complete string. However, files are usually on disks; and disks are accessed by blocks. So for reading even a single character from the file you need to read a whole block of size B (think of B as, say, 1 KiB as a reasonable example). We'll assume Max < B, otherwise you're in the huge-strings case.

Another point to be made is that disk latencies are high. This is especially true for magnetic (or optical disks), where you can wait as much as 10 msec for a single read! If you read sequentially, there's no need to "seek" or lookup the position you're interested in, and you could make use of the disk's full bandwidth. This is less of a problem with SSDs, but it's still not negligible.

So, as you can see, there's quite a bit of overhead for your binary search. It may still be worth it your file is really really large relative to Min, Max, R and B. So in a file of several Gigabytes, I'd certainly consider it. Otherwise - probably not worth the bother.